# Use semantics to prove that the postcondition is true following the execution of the program assuming the precondition is true

Tags: compilation, semantics, proof

I am trying to study for a test in my programming language concepts class.

I am trying to understand how to solve this problem. Our professor said we don't need to use formal notation to prove the problem as long as he can understand what we are saying.

I missed the lecture where he solved the problem and I'm having a very hard time finding resources to help me solve it on my own.

Would be so thankful for an explanation.

### Problem

> Use axiomatic semantics to prove that the postcondition is true following the execution of the program assuming the precondition is true

```
Precondition: n ≥ 0 and A contains n elements indexed from 0

bound = n;
while (bound > 0) {
  t = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < bound-1; i++) {
    if (A[i] > A[i+1]) {
      swap = A[i];
      A[i] = A[i+1];
      A[i+1] = swap;
      t = i+1;
    }
  }
  bound = t;
}

Postcondition: A[0] ≤ A[1] ≤ ...≤ A[n-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets number the lines for reference:

```
 1. bound = n;
 2. while (bound > 0) {
 3.  t = 0;
 4.  for (i = 0; i < bound-1; i++) {
 5.    if (A[i] > A[i+1]) {
 6.      swap = A[i];
 7.      A[i] = A[i+1];
 8.      A[i+1] = swap;
 9.      t = i+1;
10.    }
11.  }
12.  bound = t;
13. }
```

Consider the following assertions:

1. **Before entering 12**

   ```
   t < bound
   ```
2. **Before entering 11**

   `A[i] <= A[t]` for all `i` such that `0 <= i < t`
3. **Before entering 13**

   `A[k] <= A[j]` for all indexes `k` and `j` such that `bound <= k <= j <= n-1`
4. **After leaving 12**

   `bound` has decreased

---

Let's see now why the assertions are true

1. This is true because `t=0` before the loop and if set inside the `if` it is

   ```
   t = i + 1 < (bound - 1) + 1 = bound.
   ```
2. This is true because otherwise a swap would have happened.
3. This is true because of 2 and because the `for` doesn't change entries with indexes `j` from `bound` to `n-1`.
4. This is true because of 1.

---

From assertion 4 we deduce that the `while` loop, and so the algorithm, finishes in `n` steps at most, when `bound = 0`.

The postcondition now follows from assertion 3 for `bound = 0`.